# DeadLettering BrokeredMessages while Sending to a Topic in Azure Service Bus

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

In Azure Service Bus, I want a message sending to fail there are no subscriptions are defined. I achieve this by setting `EnableFilteringMessagesBeforePublishing` set to `true`, which throws the exception `NoMatchingSubscriptionException`.

Now, whilst handling this exception, I want to DeadLetter it. If I call `BrokeredMessage.DeadLetter()`, it throws `InvalidOperation` with message '`ReceiveContext is null`'

```
try
{
    await topicClient.SendAsync(brokeredMessage);
}
catch (NoMatchingSubscriptionException ex)
{
    // **throws exception** if message is attempted to move to DeadLetter queue
    await brokeredMessage.DeadLetterAsync(); 
}
```

That implies that a message can be DeadLetter'ed only when its being received, not while sending.

Is the above assumption correct?

In any case, what is the best strategy to handle a failed message sending? Is there a way failed messages while sending can end up in a DeadLetter queue for later investigation?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Deadletter queue (DLQ) is associated with a queue where message is sent. If you have no subscription (which is a queue), there's no associated DLQ either.

In regards to a strategy, you've got two questions:

1. Are there any subscribers?
2. How to handle messages that have failed sending operation?

First question is more about assumptions you're making that w/o those application should not continue. Second question is something that will definitely happen throughout application run time and you need to decide what compensating action should be taken.

Personally, I'd not necessarily enable the `EnableFilteringMessagesBeforePublishing` feature unless you absolutely need to know that there are no publishers (question #1). If you care more about the fact that message a has failed sending, rather than there were no publishers, I would suggest to have custom code that captures the failure and sends it as another type of message for control/reporting purposes into a queue that exists for sure (i.e. your application ensures it exists).